# Can a socket become writeable after an EWOULDBLOCK but before an epoll_wait?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

I have a reactor based design where a number of socket file descriptors are polled in an `epoll_wait`.

In order to optimise for latency not throughput, when writing to a socket we attempt to write directly to the file descriptor immediately.

In the event of `EWOULDBLOCK` we then buffer the unwritten data and then wait for the socket to become writeable again.

The next time our `epoll_wait` returns our file descriptor as writeable, we then send from the buffered data.

The question is, can the socket become writeable **after** we receive an `EWOULDBLOCK` but **before** we call `epoll_wait`?

That is, if we do 2 **`write`** calls, where the first **`write`** is partially written and the remainder buffered, and then do the second **`write`**, attempting to write immediately, could the socket become writeable between the first and second write call, and we end up with out-of-order data being received on the far side?

Comment: I'm not getting your concern. How would this would result in out-of-order data, assuming you don't try to send data you've already sent and aren't doing something retarded like trying to share a socket between threads without any synchronization?

Comment: @cHao no, nothing retarded like non-synchronised multi-threading! Please see my comment on the below answer by `EJP` - I suppose it's kernel threads emptying the socket send buffer that I'm worried about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is, can the socket become writeable **after** we receive an `EWOULDBLOCK` but **before** we call `epoll_wait`?

Yes, it can.  At the time of the `EWOULDBLOCK`, the socket buffer is full.  But as soon as the peer ACKs some data and space clears up in the socket buffer, the socket becomes writable again.  That happens in the background outside of your code, so the socket can become writable at *any* time.

> That is, if we do 2 `write` calls, where the first `write` is partially written and the remainder buffered, and then do the second `write`, attempting to write immediately, could the socket become writeable between the first and second write call, and we end up with out-of-order data being received on the far side?

Yes, it can.  And this would be a bug in your code logic, because you attempted to write *new data* to the socket before you finished writing any *buffered data* that was still waiting to be sent.

When you detect `EWOULDBLOCK` and start buffering data, *stop* calling `write()` for any new data until your buffer has been completely cleared.  If you need to send new data, and there is already data in your buffer, simply append the new data to the end of your buffer and move on, don't even call `write()` at all.  Whenever the socket is reported as writable, check if your buffer has any pending data in it, and if so then send as much as you can from the front of the buffer, removing successfully sent data as you go, until the buffer is cleared or `EWOULDBLOCK` is reported again.

Answer (score 3):

> Can a socket become writeable after an EWOULDBLOCK but before an epoll_wait?

Yes. It can become writable the moment there is space in the socket send buffer, which happens as soon as any prefix of the existing data in it is ACKed by the peer, asynchronously from your application.

> In order to optimise for latency not throughput, when writing to a socket we attempt to write directly to the file descriptor immediately.

Very good.

> In the event of EWOULDBLOCK we then buffer the unwritten data and then wait for the socket to become writeable again. The next time our epoll_wait returns our file descriptor as writeable, we then send from the buffered data.

VG again.

> The question is, can the socket become writeable after we receive an EWOULDBLOCK but before we call epoll_wait?

Yes, see above.

> That is, if we do 2 write calls, where the first write is partially written and the remainder buffered, and then do the second write, attempting to write immediately, could the socket become writeable between the first and second write call

Yes, see above.

> and we end up with out-of-order data being received on the far side?

I don't see how, unless you're writing to the socket from multiple threads.

Comment: No, it's single threaded. I guess I was wondering about a kernel thread making space in the socket send buffer after the `EWOULDBLOCK` but before the 2nd write, which will attempt to write to the fd immediately. Could this second write succeed because the kernel has made space in the socket send buffer?

Comment: It could, but how could that change the order in which you send data?

Comment: @cHao Given it's a reactor based design, I could attempt to do 2 writes to the same socket before I reenter the reactor loop, reenter the `epoll_wait` call, have the socket return writeable, and then write from my unsent buffer. If the first write partially sends, so half is written into the socket send buffer, the other half buffered in userspace for later, when the `epoll_wait` returns writeable again, then a kernel thread makes some space in the socket send buffer, then the second write tries to send immediately, and succeeds, and only after reenter the reactor loop and call `epoll_wait`

Comment: @SteveLorimer: If you're actually writing, though, your buffer is empty, right? Otherwise you'd be queuing up data in the buffer.

Comment: @SteveLorimer If you've buffered the remainder of the first write until polling shows it's writable, and then write something else successfully, you will get out of order data. The solution is not to try the second write if there is already buffered data: buffer the 2nd write as well, after the first.